# TYPO3 error 404 instead redicrect

Tags: typo3

I have such problem: If page on my sites doesn't exists it always does redirect at main page, but I want to display 404 error.
Example: example.com/sdasadsasad - I see main page. How I can fix it? I tried add in localconfiguration

```
    'pageNotFound_handling' = '/';
    'pageNotFound_handling_statheader' = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found';
```

but it doesn't help.
TYPO3 7.6.11

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look in the description of the install tool for the settings. There is described what setting doing what.

So an String in `pageNotFound_handling` will fetch the page entered and display this, `true` or `1` will display an error message.

I recommand to create an error page like `example.com/404.html` within TYPO3 and enter `404.html` in `pageNotFound_handling` so you can customize the error.

If you want only to shown an error enter `true`or `1` in the `pageNotFound_handling` setting.

Comment: it doesn't help. Added screen upward

Comment: So what is the value of  [FE][pageNotFound_handling] right now?

Answer (score 0):

We were experiencing the same problem. We have curl enabled ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['curlUse'] = 1). Due to our configuration, curl was not able to fetch the error page because the SSL certificate could not be verified.

Be careful, the following idea is ugly:
You might find out more about the problem by editing TypoScriptFrontendController.php: Find the function pageErrorHandler (about line 2000 -- who writes such long files?!), find the call to GernalUtility::getUrl() and add as fourth parameter a new array variable. var_dump it instead of the call to HttpUtility::redirect. You should get the curl error if there is one.